# Unzip into directory, independent if directory is contained in ZIP

Tags: shell-script, directory, zip

Let's assume I've a ZIP file whichs content may look like

```
# file: with_out_dir.zip
file1.txt
file2.cpp
file3.js
some_sub_dir/
- file_in_subdir.txt
file4.xml
```

but it may also look like this

```
# file: with_dir.zip
archive/
- file1.txt
- file2.cpp
- file3.js
- some_sub_dir/
-- file_in_subdir.txt
- file4.xml
```

and now I would have my bash script extract these files, but in any case it should to be extract to `/var/sample/` so it will like this:

```
# expected output
/var/
- sample/
-- file1.txt
-- file2.cpp
-- file3.js
-- some_sub_dir/
--- file_in_subdir.txt
-- file4.xml
```

What's the best way todo that via a `bash` script?

*At the moment I am using `unzip` to extract zip files, but I'm open for any other command line tool, if it would be easier using it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest simply:

- Extract into a fresh new directory
- If, after extraction, the new directory contains exactly one subdirectory, then move all of the files inside it up one level and get rid of the original subdirectory.

By the way, making an archive (tar, zip, whatever) *without* having all of the members of the archive inside of a subdirectory is ***EVIL***. I don't know why people do it!

Answer (score 3):

There are several smart extraction tools out there (which I found out after I wrote one for myself). You may want to look at `dtrx` ( install with `sudo apt-get install dtrx`).

`dtrx` **always** creates the toplevel directory if that is not yet in the archive. Adapting your bash wrapper script (that calls `dtrx` instead of `unzip`) then becomes much more simple as it only has to move away the subdirectories and remove the toplevel directory (as the latter is always there).

Comment: Thanks for that tipp. `dtrx` always creates a directory with the name of the ZIP file (just removing the extension), so it's even easier to store it to `/var/sample.zip` and then extract it.